# how to modify image pixels in DICOM files using Imebra library?

Tags: c++, image-processing, dicom, imebra

I use Imerba library to read DICOM files.
I need acces to pixels so I can modify them in low level.
Documentation says: "In order to access to the image's pixels you have to retrieve a data handler"
and there's an example:

```
imbxUint32 rowSize, channelPixelSize, channelsNumber;
ptr<imebra::handlers::dataHandlerNumericBase> myHandler = presentationImage->getDataHandler(true, &rowSize, &channelPixelSize, &channelsNumber);

// Retrieve the image's size in pixels
imbxUint32 sizeX, sizeY;
presentationImage->getSize(&sizeX, &sizeY);

// Scan all the rows
imbxUint32 index(0);
for(imbxUint32 scanY = 0; scanY < sizeY; ++scanY)
{
    // Scan all the columns
    for(imbxUint32 scanX = 0; scanX < sizeX; ++scanX)
    {
            // Scan all the channels
            for(imbxUint32 scanChannel = 0; scanChannel < channelsNumber; ++scanChannel)
            {
            imbxInt32 channelValue = myHandler->getSignedLong(index++);

                    // Do something with the channel's value
                    //--------------------------------------
            }
    }
```

}
I need the presentationImage object pixels to be changed. I've tried to change it in the way like:

```
myHandler->setSignedLong(index,255);
```

but it doesn't change presentationImage object and I'm now sure way. The Imebra documentation has only three examples and the classes and methods description is a bit raw. Google knows nothing as well.
How to change pixel values in this object?

Comment: I don't know the library, but a quick perusal of the docs seems to indicate that you should be passing `true` into the `getDataHandler` function.  From the docs - `true if the application wants to write into the buffer, false otherwise.`  Have you tried it passing `true` in that call?

Comment: yeah, sorry. I did that but passing true changes nothing. wrong copy here. corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

When you modify the buffer you are modifying the uncompressed image: the original dicom structure still contains the compressed image.

In order to replace the image in the Dicom file you have to put the image back into the dataset using `dataset::setImage` after the `dataHandler` goes out of scope (the data is written into the image only when the `dataHandler` is destroyed)

Comment: but how to modify pixels in image object `presentationImage`? why `myHandler->setSignedLong(index,255);` doesn't change `presentationImage`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a MutableImage object and get a WritingDataHandlerNumeric handler via MutableImage::getWritingDataHandler

https://imebra.com/wp-content/uploads/documentation/html/html/imaging_classes.html#mutableimage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).